# Find PDF of the second (later) bus coming to a stop (two bus coming to stop question)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I am waiting bus at a bus top. In the next 10 minutes, both bus A and
bus B are expected to arrive, and their arrival time are independent to each other.

X = arrival time of bus A.

Y = arrival time of bus B. 
X and Y are continuous variables, and each follows the uniform distribution over [0,10].

I have two questions regarding to this prompt.

First is let Z be the arrival time of the later of the two. How can I find the pdf of Z and the expectation E[Z]?

And second is let Z be the arrival time of the earlier of the two. How can I find the expectation E[Z] ?

Comment: You should try to add your attempts/thoughts on the problem in your post (not in comments). That way your question will be well-received.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z_1 = \min\{X,Y\}$ and $Z_2 = \max\{X,Y\}$.

- It may be easier to find the CDF of $Z_2$ first. Note that $P(Z_2 \le z) = P(X \le z, Y \le z) = P(X \le z) P(Y \le z)$. Once you have the CDF, it is straightforward to find the PDF and the expectation.
- For the second question, note that $E[Z_1] + E[Z_2] = E[Z_1 + Z_2] = E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$. So if you know $E[Z_2]$ from the previous question, then you can almost immediately find $E[Z_1]$.

Comment: The other thing I am not too sure about is that to find the probability that bus A arrives earlier than bus B. I got 1/2 because since they are independent, I basically draw a line y=x on a region 10x10 (waiting time is 10 x axis = bus A, y axis = bus B), and the region above y=x is when bus A arrives first. So I got 1/2.

Comment: @Iloveece That's right

Comment: One thing from your answer I don't understand is that P(Z2≤z)=P(X≤z,Y≤z)=P(X≤z)P(Y≤z). How can I tell I am calculating the cdf of the later bus through this ? The condition doesn't specify which bus is coming later.

Comment: @Iloveece If the later arrival is before time $z$, then both arrival times are before time $z$; the converse also holds. For the second equality, use independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: CDF I got for P(x) and P(Y) are both z/10, and their product is z^2/100. And the corresponding pdf I got is z/50. And the expectation value is integral 0 to 10 over z*z/50 which I got 6.67. Does this sound correct to you ?